# [ANDROID]Implementing Delay in Message in HandlerThread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i want to do some stuff on every few seconds in my app, for that purpose , i have implemented `HandlerThread` & `handler` via following code

```
handlerThread = new HandlerThread(getClass().getSimpleName());
        handlerThread.start();

    handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper(), new Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

            //my code here  
            return l.this.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    });
```

I initiate this handler by sending message from `onCreate()`

I handle the message as follows :

```
private boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        default:
            return false;
        case MY_MESSAGE:
            if(handler_stop==0)
            {
                checkLauncher();
                sendMessage(MY_MESSAGE); // I Send the message from here to make //this continuous       
            }



    }

    return true;
}
```

It's Working fine but it Sends message too fast , i mean constantly , instead i want this message to be sent after 2 or 3 seconds , In Short , i want to repeat task every 2-3 seconds.

How can i do this on above code ? please some one help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First declare one global varialbe for Handler to update the UI control from Thread, like below:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

Now create one Thread and use while loop to periodically perform the task using the sleep method of the thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);// change the time according to your need
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Write your code here to update the UI.
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Else just add this in your code:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          // do something             
      }}, 20000);
```

Comment: I tired that earlier , but doing the way u mentioned , it consumes much RAM, i mean the RAM taken by my app increases as time passes .. but the way i posted in my code , RAM usage of my app stays in limit.. Is there any different between ur and mine method ? how can i implement delay on the code which i wrote..

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use [Handler.sendMessageDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed)? It allows you to schedule your message to be delivered to the Handler with delay that you specify. So your code will look like this:

```
private boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        default:
            return false;
        case MY_MESSAGE:
            if(handler_stop == 0) {
                checkLauncher();
                sendMessageDelayed(MY_MESSAGE, 2000); // Send message everytime with 2 seconds delay
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i have an simple way for doing this
try this

Runnable runnable;

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            // HERE I AM CHANGING BACKGROUND YOU CAN DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
            _images[i].setBackgroundResource(imageArray[0]);
            i++;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // for interval...
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); // for initial delay..
```

worked for me hope you will also find it working

thanks

**Vote Up** if find usefull.